# Is “What does the woman suggest the man **do** for his vacation?” correct?

Tags: grammaticality, subjunctive-mood

I just went through an official English test taken in China, and I saw something rather weird. Whenever I read this sentence, something tells me that the "do" part isn't right, it simply doesn't sound right to me. Could somebody clarify this for me? Is it, or is it not correct?

> **Man**: I can't decide what to do for my summer vacation. I either want to go on a bike tour of Europe or go diving in Mexico.
>
> **Woman**: Well, we're offering an all-inclusive two-week trip to Mexico for only 300 dollars.

Question goes as follows :

> **Question :**　　What does the woman suggest the man **do** for his vacation?

Is **Do** correct? Or is it supposed to be **Does**?

Thank you for reading! Awaiting your replies.

**Edit**: As I'm quite unclear, I'm referring to the **question**, not the Man/Woman text snippet. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is perfectly correct. *Does* would be wrong, or at least worse. In this sentence, *do* is a **present subjunctive**. The verb *suggest* is normally followed either by *should* with an infinitive or by a present subjunctive, if the *that* clause after *suggest* contains that which should be done. That is the case here. The word *that* is often omitted, as it is here. The same construction is normally used with other verbs that are **mandative**, i.e. verbs that express that something should be done.

Comment: In that sentence, "do" sound extremely unnatural to me. Guess I still have work to do on my grammar. Thank you for the clear answer!

Comment: @user3697142: I understand. In informal English, people often don't use the mandative subjunctive but use the indicative (*does*) instead. Including people like David Cameron—alas, even in an official speech.

Comment: Thank you once again for the beautiful answer! Much appreciated.

Comment: @user3697142: Welcome to the website! If you appreciate an answer, you might consider voting it up (press the up arrow next to it), or even accepting it as your preferred answer (press the tick mark).

Comment: I will, do not worry. Annoying time limit :P

Comment: @user3697142: Haha, it doesn't matter anyway, just general advice, which apparently you didn't need (I already have all the reputation points I need).